# .AAC Recorded Audio not playing in swift

Tags: swift, ios9, avaudioplayer, swift2

I have recorded audio in .AAC format using microphone and  successfully saved in document directory.When i try to play particular recorded audio  it is not playing but play methods are calling,Am not getting any sound in microphone . If any one can help me to figure out this issue

Recording Audio sample code below

```
 func record() {
    self.prepareToRecord()
    if let recorder = self.audioRecorder {
        recorder.record()
    }
}
func prepareToRecord() {


    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let currentDateTime = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy-HHmmss"
    str_Recordedname = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime)+".AAC"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, str_Recordedname]
    let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
    print(filePath)

    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2 as NSNumber,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue
    ]


    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL:filePath!, settings:[:])
        self.audioRecorder!.meteringEnabled = true
        self.audioRecorder!.prepareToRecord()
        self.audioRecorder!.record()
        self.audioRecorder!.delegate = self


        print("Recorded Audio is",filePath!)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print(error.description)
    }

}
```

Playing Sample code is

```
    var filePath =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    print("\nfilePath: \(filePath)")

    filePath = filePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(self.str_Recordedname)
    print("\nfilePath: \(filePath)")

    let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath as String)
    print("\nfilePathURL: \(filePathURL)")



    do {
        var player = AVPlayer()

        let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: filePathURL)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Edit:

Removed AVPlayer Variable from Locally and pasted Globally its worked

Comment: Move the declaration of var player = AVPlayer() out of your method otherwise it goes out of existence once the method finishes. It should be a property of your View Controller class not a property of your View Controller method

Comment: you should consider also naming your audio in a way that it gets automatically sorted by date yyyyMMdd-HHmmss

Comment: @LeoDabus:Thanks mate its working ,U saved my day